# What is the right way to make and retrieve a object if none is found using hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to check if there is an timesheet with a given id. If none is found I want to save a new one and retrieve its data. The code below saves the object on first rest call, then if I make a new call it will save again the same object. If I make a third call I will get a server error.

```java
@Override
public TimesheetVO getTimesheet(LocalDate date) {
    Timesheet timesheet = timesheetRepository.findByDate(date).orElse(timesheetRepository.save(new Timesheet(date, 8, tasks)));

    List<TaskVO> taskVOS = timesheet.getTasks().stream().map(i -> taskMapper.transformToVO(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    TimesheetVO timesheetVO = timesheetMapper.transformToVO(timesheet);
    timesheetVO.setTasks(taskVOS);

    return timesheetVO;
}
```

Should I write the code like:

```java
@Override
public TimesheetVO getTimesheet(LocalDate date) {
    Optional<Timesheet> timesheetOpt = timesheetRepository.findByDate(date);
    Timesheet timesheet;

    if(timesheetOpt.isEmpty()){
        timesheetRepository.save(new Timesheet(date, 8, tasks));
        timesheet = timesheetRepository.findByDate(date).orElseThrow();
    } else {
        timesheet = timesheetOpt.get();
    }

    List<TaskVO> taskVOS = timesheet.getTasks().stream().map(i -> taskMapper.transformToVO(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    TimesheetVO timesheetVO = timesheetMapper.transformToVO(timesheet);
    timesheetVO.setTasks(taskVOS);

    return timesheetVO;
}
```

or is there a more elegant way to do the same thing?

Comment: The first one is the right one, although you should use `orElseGet` instead of `orElse`. The second one is abusing `Optional`. Another thing your `TimesheetMapper` should internally convert the `Task` to `TaskVO` you shouldn't be needing to do that externally. Also if `tasks` is a shared list, don't do that as that will lead to other issues.

Comment: Works now! Thank you!